# Alternatives to Love2D for a Lua 2D Graphics Lib

Tags: graphics, lua, recommendation-engine

I'm looking for alternatives to the Love2D graphics/game library which ideally would support the following:

- Easy primitive rendering (e.g. points, lines, 2d polygons)
- Ability to load and draw images
- basic text rendering (though something more full-featured would be nice)

Do any others exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) and [LuaCairo](http://www.dynaset.org/dogusanh/pgluacairo.html).

Comment: This is great for image making, but if i wanted something that drew to a window what would i use? Or would cairo do that too?

Comment: Cairo's web page says it support X11 and Win32 among several others.

Answer (score 3):

Try also [Canvas Draw](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/cd/).

Comment: I'll take a look at that too, it seems to come with a standard Lua install.

Comment: CD works quite well used in combination with IUP to provide the UI framework needed to be a well-behaved Windows GUI application.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) framework, which has a Lua binding named [wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/). It is included in the [Lua for Windows](http://luaforwindows.luaforge.net/) batteries-included distribution, and should be as platform-portable as either Lua or wxWidgets itself.